# What is the site-rec tag for if recommendations are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation, off-topic

If recommendations are *mostly* off-topic across Stack Exchange, how is that the [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) exists?

> Q: Recommend me a SE site where I can ask about X recommendation
>
> A: None, recommendations are off-topic

Comment: I've answered plenty of `site-rec` questions, I don't see them as off-topic, usually. What question was closed as off-topic?

Comment: I'm confused, are you talking about the main site or Meta? (you are linking to a main site tag)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The questions refers to the tag on SO (not the one on MSO).

Comment: @N.N.: How are you sure about that?

Comment: @N.N. The tag doesn't exist on the main site. (The tag page exists, but that doesn't necessarily mean the tag itself does, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-tag-doesn't-exist)

Comment: @Mat: Exactly my point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The [link was initially](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/157926/2) to the SO tag.

Comment: are these questions examples of what you ask about? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157789 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157569 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155818 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155412 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149151 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147641 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139511 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146487

Comment: @N.N.: That's because the `[tag:...]` syntax links to main-site tags not MSO tags, which is confusing for first-time users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recommendations *for an SE site* are *meta* recommendations, and so are *on* topic here on meta.

Note that I am answering the question as edited to be about the *meta* tag, which is not what was originally asked.

<sup><sub>Sorry about *the* excessive italics</sub></sup>